# aws-node pod is missing in kube-system namespace

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Im deploying EKS cluster and configuring the managed node groups so that we can have master and worker nodes .
following this doc :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-iam-role.html

while running this command :

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=aws-node
```

I dont see any POD with that label . dont know why ?
Is it something due to missing configuration OR I missed something while deploying EKS cluster

please suggest

**UPDATE 1**

```
kubectl describe daemonset aws-node -n kube-system
```

output

```
Name:           aws-node Selector:       k8s-app=aws-node Node-Selector:  <none> Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/instance=aws-vpc-cni
                app.kubernetes.io/name=aws-node
                app.kubernetes.io/version=v1.11.4
                k8s-app=aws-node Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 2 Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 0 Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 0 Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 0 Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 0 Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0 Pods Status:  0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed Pod Template:   Labels:   app.kubernetes.io/instance=aws-vpc-cni
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=aws-node
                    k8s-app=aws-node   Service Account:  aws-node
```

Comment: Which pods are listed in -n kube-system namespace?

Comment: it seems that daemonset object with the name aws-node exist . however, there is no any pod with name aws-node. See UPDATE 1

Comment: in the kube-system namespace , only core-dns pods are there and those are in pending state

Comment: Can you paste the output of `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: kubectl get nodes command says No resources found

Answer (score 1):

> kubectl get nodes command says No resources found

No pod will be running if you don't have any worker node. Easiest way to add worker node is on the AWS console, goto Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service and click on your cluster, goto "Compute" tab and select the node group, click "Edit" and change "Desired size" to > 1.